# cannot resolve Extra argument 'onError' in call error

Tags: observable, rx-swift

I am trying to subscribe to an observable. What could be the reason for the error  Extra argument 'onError' in call ?
Can someone help me debug find the issue. 
[image]

in my **ViewModel**

```
func loadImages() {
            return dataController.fetchStatusCodeImages()
                .subscribe(
                   onNext: { images in
                   self.imagesDataSource.value = images
                },
                    onError: { error in
                    print("observer error")
                    //empty - handle error cases here
                    if let err = error as? NetworkError {
                        switch err {
                        case .invalidURL:
                            self.isInvalid.value = true
                        case .emptyResponse:
                            self.isInvalid.value = true
                        }
                    }
                    //error cases
                }, onCompleted: {
                    print("completed")
                }, onDisposed: {

                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        }
```

and in the **dataController**

```
func loadImages() {
        return dataController.fetchStatusCodeImages()
            .subscribe(
               onNext: { images in
               self.imagesDataSource.value = images
            },
                onError: { error in
                print("observer error")
                //empty - handle error cases here
                if let err = error as? NetworkError {
                    switch err {
                    case .invalidURL:
                        self.isInvalid.value = true
                    case .emptyResponse:
                        self.isInvalid.value = true
                    }
                }
                //error cases
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("completed")
            }, onDisposed: {

            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have an Observable with a trait.

For an `Observable` your code would be OK:

```
        Observable.of([1,2,3])
        .subscribe(onNext: { (n) in
            //
        }, onError: { (error) in
            //
        }, onCompleted: {
            //
        }, onDisposed: {
            //
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

If the observable has the `Single` or `Maybe` trait, you need a different form:

```
    Observable.of(1).asSingle()
        .subscribe(onSuccess: { (n) in
            //
        }, onError: { (error) in
            //
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```